# Получение данных о пользователе ВК через OpenAPI

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Использую  [OpenAPI](https://vk.com/dev/openapi_auth), но не могу получить данные о пользователе. Имя, фамилию и Id. Подскажите, как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Для начала в шапке надо подключить `openapi.js` вот так:

```
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Далее необходимо инициализировать приложение со своим идентификатором в `body`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    VK.init({
        apiId: 666
    });         
</script>
```

Далее авторизовываемся. Если успешно авторизовался, то данные пользователя **уже** придут в ответе

```
VK.Auth.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        showAuthData(response.session);

        if (response.settings) {
            console.log(response.settings);
            // Выбранные настройки доступа пользователя если они были запрошены
        }
    } else {
        // Пользователь нажал кнопку Отмена в окне авторизации 
    }
}); 


function showAuthData(data) {
    $('body').append('<p>expire: ' + data.expire +'</p>');
    $('body').append('<p>mid: ' + data.mid +'</p>');
    $('body').append('<p>fio: ' + data.user.first_name + ' ' + data.user.last_name +'</p>');
    $('body').append('<p>userDomain: ' + data.user.domain +'</p>');
    $('body').append('<p>-----------------------------------------------</p>');
}
```

Если хочется отдельно обратиться к любому методу `API` после авторизации, то надо писать так:

```
VK.Api.call(METHOD, PARAMS, CALLBACK);
```

где

- METHOD (string) — название метода `API`;
- PARAMS (object) — параметры метода;
- CALLBACK (function) — функция обратного вызова.

**[см. документацию...](https://vk.com/dev/openapi_2?f=4.%2B%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%2B%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%2BAPI%2B%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)**

Например:

```
VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: 1}, function(r) {
  if(r.response) {
    alert('Привет, ' + r.response[0].first_name);
  }
});
```

Это вызовет метод [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get) - и достанет данные пользователя с идентификатором `1`

Comment: Подключил код, как у вас. Но сразу после того, как выскакивает попап, он закрывается почему-то

Comment: @Andrey видимо сразу логинит как владельца.. можете проверить тоже самое например в хроме в режиме инкогнито (только надо будет разрешить всплывающее окно) - тогда сразу увидите

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом вам надо [зарегистрировать своё приложение ВК](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create) (тип указать «веб-сайт») – и скопировать ID приложения:

[image: настройки приложения ВК]

В Настройках вашего приложения надо указать тот домен, с которого ваш код будет работать. Если его скопировать на другой домен – работать перестанет.

В [документации ВК по OpenAPI](https://vk.com/dev/openapi) есть примеры кода. Вот они с небольшими изменениями:

```
<div id="b-user"></div> <!-- сюда выведем имя пользователя -->
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script> <!-- скрипт openapi -->
```

И JavaScript:

```
VK.init({ apiId: 5599725 }); // зарегистрировал VK-приложение
// тут: https://vk.com/editapp?act=create
// в Настройках нужно указать свой домен, откуда будет работать код

VK.Auth.login(function(response) {
  var el = document.getElementById('b-user');

  if (response.session) {
    /* Пользователь успешно авторизовался */

    if (response.session.mid && response.session.user) {
      el.innerHTML = 'Привет, <a href="https://vk.com/id%UID%" target="_blank">%USERNAME%</a>!'
        .replace('%USERNAME%', response.session.user.first_name + ' ' + response.session.user.last_name)
        .replace('%UID%', response.session.user.id);
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = 'данные пользователя не пришли что-то';
    }

  } else {
    /* Пользователь нажал кнопку Отмена в окне авторизации */
    el.innerHTML = 'Пользователь не согласился';
  }
});
```

[Рабочий пример](https://deserter.io/stackoverflow/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Работает, но мое поп-ап окно сразу логинит меня, без запроса на подтверждение, возможно, из-за того, что я владелец.

Comment: Да, вас, как владельца, не спрашивает. У других юзеров возникнет попап (если не заблокированы настройками браузера) с запросом разрешения на доступ к аккаунту.

Comment: Если не сложно, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы это окно вызывалось по клику на элемент и просто получало даные, а то я пробовал, и оно просто вызывалось, без клика, при загрузке страницы

Comment: `VK.Auth.login` вызывайте по событию клика на ваш элемент.